# Canvas triangle without linejoin and stroke width

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have this triangle that I have rounded corners on but I'm using the `arcTo`:

```
context.moveTo(140, 0);
context.arcTo(180, 100, 100, 100, 4);
context.arcTo(100, 100, 140, 0, 4);
context.arcTo(140, 0, 180, 100, 4);
```

As you will see the top angle looks a bit messed up. Any ideas how to fix it? Seems like there needs to be some calculations for the initial `moveTo(x, y)` but `140, 0` is where it should start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got rid of the `moveTo` and arced them to eachother. Started the first part at 174, 176 (180-4 radius) works but 174 had no overlap at all.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/XeqTr/)**

```
​var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0],
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = canvas.height = 400;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arcTo(174, 100, 100, 100, 4);
ctx.arcTo(100, 100, 140, 0, 4);
ctx.arcTo(140, 0, 180, 100, 4);
ctx.arcTo(180, 100, 100, 100, 4);
ctx.stroke();
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
var r = 8;
var offset = (6 * r / 4) - 1;

context.arcTo((180 - offset), 100, 100, 100, r);
context.arcTo(100, 100, 140, 0, r);
context.arcTo(140, 0, 180, 100, r);
context.arcTo(180, 100, 100, 100, r);
```

Using part of what Loktar provided, I've modified it slightly to use a ratio of what I know works for a given diameter, and used this as the offset. With a diameter of 4, I know 6 works.

Seems like there should be a better way but I'm happy with this.